# Where is the Default App config file located on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, config, default, windows-11

I would like to access the file from which the following is read off.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for where Windows keep "Films & TV should open .3gpp" or where Films & TV declare it can read .3gpp?

Comment: I am looking for the former.

Comment: You shouldn't need to access this information. If you have a file with a particular extension, you can just ask the shell to run the file and it'll pick the program the user selected. And you can't change it programmatically because [bad things happen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413): "This childish game of “Nuh-uh/Yuh-huh!” went on while the user sat there dumbfounded and helpless, watching the icon for their .XYZ files flicker back and forth between the two programs ... by insisting on being the program that runs .XYZ files."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File types/associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-file-types) are stored in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT part of the registry.

Which application (which ProgId technically) is the default for a specific file extension is stored inside the undocumented HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts key. The UserChoice is hashed to prevent people from changing the default.